How Kubernetes deployment scaling down happens
I have a kubernetes deployment running. Let's call it "my-spboot-deployment".
This deployment has 2 replicas running in two different worker nodes. (I have used node affinity for provisioning). These two worker nodes are from two different geographical locations.
pod 1 ---> node 1 
pod 2 ---> node 2 

now i need to scale down this deployment into one pod and my expectation is terminating the pod2 which is running in node 2. But when I execute kubectl scale deployment my-spboot-deployment --replicas=1 , it always terminates the pod1 which is running in node1.
I just need to know how kubernetes decides which pod to terminate when we command to scale down. Is that just random or any algorithm behind it.
My second question is, in this kind of scenario how can I purposely bring down pod2 in node2. Any possible way of doing that? (I can't bring down docker or kubelet service in those worker nodes. It will impact other services running on those)
**I don't want to re-deploy by adding a new node label.

Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or DevOps. These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

Question 1:
The ReplicaSet controller considers the following things in scaling down algorithm according to official k8s documentation (link).

Pending (and unschedulable) pods are scaled down first
If controller.kubernetes.io/pod-deletion-cost annotation is set, then the pod with the lower value will come first
Pods on nodes with more replicas come before pods on nodes with fewer replicas.
If the pods' creation times differ, the pod that was created more recently comes before the older pod.

Question 2:
To set a preference regarding which pods to remove first, you can use controller.kubernetes.io/pod-deletion-cost annotation (link).
